# reading the values of a nested JSON in PHP Laravel

Tags: php

I have a JSON `$json`:

```
{
    "Animal": "Human",
    "Category": [
        {
            "Name": "A",
            "Color": ["black", "Red"]
        },
        {
            "Name": "B",
            "Color": ["Orange", "Yellow"]
        },
        {
            "Name": "C",
            "Color": ["Purple", "black"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to read the value of Color and check if Red is part of Color value or not. My code is as follow

```
$sample = json_decode($json);
foreach ($sample->Category as $eachCategory) {
   foreach ($eachCategory->Color as $colour) {
      if ('Red' === $colour) {
         // do something here
      }                    
   }
}
```

But while executing this line `foreach ($eachCategory->Color as $colour)` my code is getting failed and throwing error `Undefined property: stdClass::$Color`. My question is am I reading the Color values correctly `$eachCategory->Color` if not then how can I read the values and use that to compare further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly is your code getting "failed"?

Comment: Your code is correct. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine , please elaborate what error you are facing?

Comment: "Failed" how? We cannot guess your error.

Comment: I am getting error stating `Undefined property: stdClass::$Color`

Comment: Then either the JSON you've given use is not what you're actually using, the code you've given us is not what you're actually using, or both. Because [it works as-is](https://3v4l.org/Q5bq2).

Comment: this is very strange, I am using the same code and still getting the above error message while fetching `$eachCategory->Color`

Answer (score -2):

I sincerely, couldn't spot why your code fails as it worked properly when I tried it. It might depends on how you accept json data in your request. Besides, I would suggest this implementation below:

```
$sample = json_decode($json, true); // Add true as second parameter to have the JSON parsed to the array nestedly.

// Use array_column to collect the values of 'Color' column to a new array
// Use array_reduce to kind of unwrap the array
$colors = array_reduce(
    array_column($sample['Category'], 'Color'),
    'array_merge',
    array()
);
$exists = in_array('Red',$colors);
var_dump($exists);
```